# Exception when saving object containing a dropdownlistvalue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to save an object that contains a value coming from a dropdownbox (SelectList). I am getting a Nullpoint for some reason when trying to save. The Nullpointer is thrown in the piece of code that you see in my view below:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoleName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Roles, new SelectList(Model.Roles, "Value", "Value"), new { @class = "text-danger AddMemberControls" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I chose a value from the dropdown on the screen, then click save, but it seems the model doesn't pass on the value.
My model (ViewModel) looks like this:

```
public class AdminViewModel
{
    public int MemberID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string MemberEmail { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }

    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

The controller looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddAdmin(AdminViewModel model)
    {
        //var selectedVal = new SelectList(model.Roles);

        if(ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
            var admin = new Admin()
            {
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                MemberEmail = model.MemberEmail
               // RoleName = selectedVal.DataTextField
                ...
            };
        }
        ...
        return View("AddAdmin");
    }
```

When running in debug mode, the `ModelState.IsValid` evaluates to false, and then the view throws the exception mentioned above.

In case you want to see how I populate the Dropdownlist in my `HttpHet`, here is the code

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddAdmin()
    {
        DataAccessLayer.ColoContext col = new DataAccessLayer.ColoContext();

        List<Roles> list = new List<Roles>(col.Roles.ToList());
        AdminViewModel viewMod = new AdminViewModel();                         

        //viewMod.Roles = new SelectList(list);

        viewMod.Roles = col.Roles.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
        {
             Value = x.RoleName,
             Text = x.RoleDescription
        }).ToList();

        return View(viewMod);
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean a `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: Yes a nullreference. Sorry. The reason why I didnt add the errormessage, is that it's not in English, so not many would understand it anyway

Comment: The linked duplicate has considerable information about what a `NullReferenceException` means and how to address it.  Basically somewhere in your code you are trying to use an object which is `null`.  You need to determine the line of code throwing the exception and the object on that line which is `null`.  Then either modify the code to handle a `null` value in that object or trace back to where the object came from and correct that code to provide a valid object instead of `null`.

Comment: In your case it seems likely that `Model.Roles` is throwing the error.  You're trying to dereference the `Model` object, but you're not passing a model to the view: `return View("AddAdmin");`